# Por que chamar o System.gc() não garante execução do garbage collector?

Tags: java, gerenciamento-de-memória, garbage-collector, jvm

Por que o desenvolvedor não tem total controle sobre o *garbage collector*?

Entendo que o papel do GC é gerenciar automaticamente a memória. Mas por que mesmo usando algum método como o `System.gc()` não há garantia de que o GC será executado?

Comment: Arrisco dizer que boa parte do motivo da linguagem não obrigar a executar é porque senão os programadores novatos querendo resolver _memory leaks_ iriam ficar disparando a torto e a direito no código uma operação potencialmente custosa (e, conforme o caso, bloqueante) que é a coleta de lixo, e poderiam acabar sobrecarregando suas aplicações.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É possível ter controle sobre o coletor de lixo, isso apenas não ocorre com o Java na sua implementação padrão, até onde eu sei, também por força de especificação. Vou responder baseado no contexto da pergunta.

A [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) da linguagem não dá detalhes sobre o funcionamento do GC, não exige que ele funcione ou deixe de funcionar em determinado momento, que ele seja implementado com uma técnica específica, que seja concorrente ou não, síncrono ou não, não especifica como deve ser seu tempo de resposta, tão pouco quando ele deve ocorrer.

O GC atual na implementação mais conhecida do Java funciona da forma mostrada na documentação do GC. Isso pode ser mudado desde que não fira a especificação da linguagem. E o GC é uma das coisas que mais muda em Java. Os maldosos dizem que ela precisa ter uma GC cada vez melhor porque ela gera muito lixo (e é verdade). Quando ler isso o GC pode ser diferente e isso pode valer mais ou menos.

## Gerações

O principal motivo para que o GC não garanta nada é que ele pode piorar uma situação. Na implementação atual há um sistema de gerações. Quando você chama o GC forçando uma coleta, pensa que vai diminuir possíveis latências no meio de um processamento. E pode estar fazer justamente o contrário, o sistema de gerações é bem complexo e foi criado justamente para diminuir as latências quando ele é invocado.

Se o usuário dele, o programador, força uma coleta, ele está apenas jogando dados "vivos" de uma geração para a outra e atualmente só existem 3 delas. Quando o objeto cai na última geração, a vantagem da latência baixa se perde. Coletar na última geração é algo que o GC deve evitar. Para isto o melhor a fazer é evitar que o dado chegue lá, ou que só ocorra quando realmente é necessário, quando o dado tem um tempo de vida realmente longo.

Chamar o GC antecipa sua chamada e pode jogar um objeto para a última geração sem necessidade, e aí coletas passarão custar mais caro com mais frequência.

Eu poderia entrar em mais detalhes, mas não é algo tão importante. O GC foi feito para que você não se preocupe como ele funciona internamente.

## Diversas implementações

O fato de não ser garantido não significa que nada será feito, caso contrário não teria sentido haver uma chamada explícita para ele.

Note que existem GCs para o Java mais simples que isto. Eles podem executar sempre e podem ser efetivos, mas não conte com isto.

O problema é justamente no comportamento não padrão. Você não pode especificar um comportamento padrão para necessidades diferentes, sob pena de inviabilizar certas implementações. E você não pode especificar algo que vai funcionar às vezes. A especificação toma o caminho seguro de dizer que garante nada, assim ninguém programa pensando que pode se beneficiar de algum comportamento do GC.

Você pode até mesmo ter configurações que mudam o comportamento do GC.

Por isso é perigoso programar na base do "funcionou na minha máquina" ou o "eu testei e deu certo". Tem que programar baseado na especificação.

É um erro fazer isto, mas se tiver conhecimento que uma implementação de GC que você vai usar pode beneficiar seu código em alguma situação, a tal ponto que justifique ignorar isso, então pode usar. Aceite o risco e controle a aplicação para que não use outro tipo de GC. Em 99,999% dos casos, ou um pouco mais, você não deve fazer isso.

## Obtendo controle total da memória

Se precisa controlar a memória mais do que isto, não use Java. Cada linguagem tem sua filosofia, seus pontos fortes e fracos. Java nunca se preocupou com o uso parcimonioso da memória, seu forte está em outro ponto, que é não ter que se preocupar com o gerenciamento de memória.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 10):

Porque é assim que a linguagem foi projetada. Isso pode ser visto na documentação oficial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29

Agora é claro que isso levanta a pergunta: **por que a linguagem foi projetada assim**?

Isso tem a ver a tanto com a filosofia da linguagem (não interessa ao programador Java o gerenciamento explícito de memória) quanto com razões práticas: catar o lixo é um processo caro. Veja isso:

> When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine
>   has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

Ou seja, quando o controle retorna ao código que chamou o método, a JVM fez tudo o que podia para catar o lixo que havia. Isso significa que a chamada é **síncrona**. Processo caro + chamada síncrona = sua aplicação esperar muito tempo para realmente continuar a rodar.

Isso pode ser problemático, então, em diferentes cenários, a JVM pode decidir que não fazer a coleta completa do lixo é a melhor escolha. A JVM também pode ser manualmente configurada para ignorar o `System.gc()`.

É claro que existem situações nas quais pode ser uma boa ideia chamar o GC. Por exemplo, durante um jogo, pode ser que você queira chamar o GC durante a tela de carregamento, em vez de esperar ele rodar e pausar todo o sistema quando o usuário está realmente jogando. Por isso a chamada continua existindo. Apenas não confie a ela a corretude da sua aplicação.

Answer (score 8):

## TL;DR

Porque *Garbage Collector* (GC) é mais um conceito do que exatamente um algoritmo ou conjunto de classes ou API.

**Toda garantia limita a forma como ele pode ser implementado.**

## Vamos por partes...

> Por que chamar o `System.gc` não garante execução do garbage collector?

Existem muitas formas de implementar um GC: [concorrente e paralelo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#cms), [contínuo](https://www.azul.com/resources/azul-technology/azul-c4-garbage-collector/), etc. Em muitos casos não faz sentido algum chamar essa rotina explicitamente.

Se a especificação garantisse a execução na chamada, ela estaria limitando a forma como o GC pode ser implementado. E é exatamente isso que eles querem evitar.

Implementações mais simples e síncronas do GC executam quando se chama o `System.gc()`, mas note que este é um comportamento da implementação e não da especificação.

> Por que o desenvolvedor não tem total controle sobre o garbage collector?

Você não pode ter total controle sobre o funcionamento interno de algo que funciona como uma caixa preta.

Na verdade, você pode sim ter o controle sobre certos aspectos do GC quando você sabe com antecedência qual é a implementação de uma certa JVM que está executando seu sistema. Existem vários artigos na internet que vão lhe ensinar a lidar com as configurações do GC de cada JVM.

> Entendo que o papel do GC é gerenciar automaticamente a memória mas por que mesmo usando algum método como o System.gc não há garantia de que o GC será executado?

"*Automaticamente*" é a palavra chave. Não é feito para ser manualmente, pelos motivos já citados acima.

## Uma analogia

Uma analogia talvez ilustre bem a situação. Imagine se a pergunta fosse assim:

> Por que `Set` não garante a ordem dos elementos do conjunto?

Porque segundo o conceito de conjuntos não existe ordem, mas existem implementações da interface `Set` que mantém a ordem, as quais você pode usar quando tiver a necessidade.