# Java acusa valores errados de uso de memória ou há algo errado com o algoritmo?

Tags: java, memória, garbage-collector

Estava estudando GC e surgiu a dúvida quando rodei o executei abaixo:

```
public class Garbage
{

    public static long carregarMemoria()
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            list.add(i);
        }

        return Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        int MB = 1_048_576; //Bytes em um MB;

        long total = rt.maxMemory() / MB;

        long memUtil = total - carregarMemoria() / MB;

        System.out.println("Mem. total: " + total + "MB");

        System.out.println("Mem. util após sobrecarga: " + memUtil + "MB");

        rt.runFinalization();
        rt.gc();

        memUtil = total - rt.freeMemory() / MB;

        System.out.println("Mem. util após gc: " + memUtil + "MB");
    }

}
```

Saída:

> Mem. total: 1808MB
>
> Mem. util após sobrecarga: 1690MB
>
> Mem. util após gc: 1686MB

1686 MB é uma memória considerável para um programa tão simples, verifiquei no gerenciador de tarefas e ele não acusa uma utilização abrupta de memória. Estou utilizando o Eclipse e o gerenciador diz que ele utiliza 430MB, quando rodo o código há um acréscimo ~15MB.

Há algo errado com o código? Porque não consigo ver esse uso de memória no gerenciador de tarefas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O gerenciador de tarefas não é confiável para ver quanto de memória está sendo usada. Além disso é preciso entender o que cada número significa de verdade. O consumo muitas vezes é um pouco enganoso. Existe diferença entre memória reservada e efetivamente utilizada, só para citar o principal.

Não há nada de errado com o código. Você acaba de descobrir que Java é devorador de memória. Eu falo sobre isso em [Qual a razão de Java consumir tanta memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52517/101). Não vou repetir aqui o que já está lá. Tem muita coisa que ocupa a memória mesmo não usando.

## Esse exemplo

Tem um consumo específico em um **array** com 100 mil `Integer`. Se for 32 bits só de ponteiros para os inteiros já são 400KB ocupado só pelo *array*. Se for 64 bits, sobe para 800KB.

Depois tem as instâncias. Não sei quanto o Java está consumindo atualmente, mas parece que tinha um *overhead* de 16 bytes do objeto, se for 32 bits. Mais, pelo menos, 4 bytes do valor em si. Então pelo menos 20 bytes vezes 100 mil, dá 2MB. Em 64 bits seria 3.6MB (note que os números podem não ser exatamente estes, mas dá uma base como ocupa muito proporcionalmente).

É muito ou é pouco dependendo de como vê. É pouco no total. Mas se considerar que C, C++, C# e outras linguagens vão ocupar apenas 400KB independente da arquitetura, é muito.

## *Garbage Collector*

Outro detalhe é que em condições normais não deveria chamar o `gc()`. Entendo que para teste tudo bem, mas nem sempre ele fará o que espera. Falo sobre isso em algumas perguntas:

- [Por que chamar o System.gc não garante execução do garbage collector?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105092/101)
- [Em quais momentos se faz necessário forçar a coleta de lixo em C# para um melhor desempenho da aplicação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101)