# Garbage Collector do VisualVM

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collector

Possuo uma aplicação Java Web utilizando Spring rodando em Tomcat 7.0. Com o passar dos dias, o uso da memória sobe lentamente e não desce muito, embora pelo VisualVM percebo que o GC é executado com frequência. Mas apenas do executar o GC do VisualVM, clicando no botão, a memória da aplicação é de fato liberada em grande quantidade. Por que isso acontece? Já fiz tunning na aplicação e não parece ser o caso de memory leak, visto que o GC do VisualVM libera a memória. Alguma dica de como melhorar esta situação? Configurando GC, utilizando Tomcat 8.0?

Comment: Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105092/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159846/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52517/101, veja se te ajuda.

Comment: @bigown São bons artigos de fato, o problema é que continuo sem saber o que fazer na aplicação, visto que depois de dias executando a memória só volta ao normal se eu executar o GC do VisualVM.

Comment: Pela sua pergunta, é só o que dá para responder. Ou você precisar fazer uma pergunta que possa ser respondida ou deve contratar alguma consultoria.