# Objetos elegíveis para o GC

Tags: java, objetos, instanciar-objeto, garbage-collector, jvm

Tenho a seguinte questão de certificação sobre o *garbage collector*:

```
1: public class Rabbit {
2: public static void main(String[] args) {
3: Rabbit one = new Rabbit();
4: Rabbit two = new Rabbit();
5: Rabbit three = one;
6: one = null;
7: Rabbit four = one;
8: three = null;
9: two = null;
10: two = new Rabbit();
11: System.gc();
12: } }
```

E as seguintes respostas:

1. O objeto Rabbit da linha 3 é elegível primeiro para a coleta de lixo imediatamente após a linha 8.
2. O objeto Rabbit da linha 4 é primeiro elegível para coleta de lixo imediatamente após a linha 9.

Na resposta dois entendi que ao colocar 9: two = null; a partir dessa linha ele ja fica elegível para o garbage collector.

Porém, na primeira poderiam me explicar porque ele fica elegível após linha 8.
Uma vez que temos a linha `7: Rabbit four = one;` Segue figura do que eu compreendi fazendo conforme indica o guia oficial da certificação.

[image: imagem dos objetos]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que fica mais fácil entender se refizermos os desenhos, vendo o que acontece linha a linha.

---

#### Linha 3:

```
Rabbit one = new Rabbit();
```

Aqui é criada uma instância de `Rabbit`, para a qual a variável `one` aponta. Ou seja:

[image: linha 3]

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| one | Rabbit criado na linha 3 |

---

#### Linha 4:

```
Rabbit two = new Rabbit();
```

Criamos outra instância de `Rabbit` e atribuimos na variável `two`:

[image: linha 4]

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| one | Rabbit criado na linha 3 |
| two | Rabbit criado na linha 4 |

---

#### Linha 5:

```
Rabbit three = one;
```

A variável `three` aponta para o mesmo local onde `one` está apontando (ou seja para o `Rabbit` criado na linha 3):

[image: linha 5]

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| one | Rabbit criado na linha 3 |
| two | Rabbit criado na linha 4 |
| three | Rabbit criado na linha 3 |

Até aqui tudo bem, temos 2 instâncias de `Rabbit` e 3 variáveis, sendo que duas delas (`one` e `three`) apontam para uma instância de `Rabbit` e uma (`two`) aponta para a outra instância.

---

#### Linha 6:

Agora acho que é o ponto que te deixou confuso:

```
one = null;
```

Aqui fazemos a variável `one` apontar para `null`. Ou seja, ela deixa de apontar para a instância de `Rabbit`:

[image: linha 6]

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| one | null |
| two | Rabbit criado na linha 4 |
| three | Rabbit criado na linha 3 |

Repare que somente a variável `one` é nula, mas `three` ainda continua apontando para a instância de `Rabbit`. E como cada uma das instâncias de `Rabbit` ainda contém referências a elas, nenhuma está elegível para o GC.

Mas por que `three` não fica nula, se ela apontava para o mesmo local que `one`? Isso acontece porque as variáveis não são o objeto em si, e sim referências para ele. Fazendo uma analogia, imagine que eu tenho duas folhas de papel e escrevo meu endereço em ambas. As duas têm uma referência para o mesmo endereço, mas nenhuma delas **é** o local de fato (elas só apontam para o local, só têm um referência que indica onde é). Se eu rasgar/queimar/triturar uma das folhas, a outra continuará intacta e apontando para o endereço.

É isso que acontece aqui: `one` e `three` apontavam para o mesmo objeto (para a instância de `Rabbit` criada na linha 3). Ao deixar `one` nula (ao "rasgar o papel"), somente ela deixa de apontar para o objeto, mas `three` não é afetada e continua apontando.

---

#### Linha 7:

```
Rabbit four = one;
```

Aqui criamos outra variável (`four`) e fazemos ela apontar para o mesmo lugar onde `one` está apontando. Mas lembre-se que `one` agora é `null`, então `four` também o será:

[image: linha 7]

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| one | null |
| two | Rabbit criado na linha 4 |
| three | Rabbit criado na linha 3 |
| four | null |

Ou seja, as duas instâncias de `Rabbit` continuam tendo referências apontando para elas, e portanto ainda não estão elegíveis para o GC.

---

#### Linha 8:

```
three = null;
```

Agora sim `three` passa a ser `null`:

[image: linha 8]

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| one | null |
| two | Rabbit criado na linha 4 |
| three | null |
| four | null |

E veja que agora sim a instância de `Rabbit` criada na linha 3 não tem mais ninguém apontando para ela, e portanto ela passa a ser elegível para o GC.

---

#### Linha 9:

```
two = null;
```

`two` passa a ser `null`, ou seja:

[image: linha 9]

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| one | null |
| two | null |
| three | null |
| four | null |

Então agora o segundo `Rabbit` (que foi criado na liinha 4) não tem mais nenhuma referência a ele, e portanto também fica elegível para o GC.

---

#### Linha 10:

```
two = new Rabbit();
```

É criado uma nova instância de `Rabbit`, para a qual `two` aponta:

[image: linha 10]

| variável | valor |
| --- | --- |
| one | null |
| two | Rabbit criado na linha 10 |
| three | null |
| four | null |

---

Vale lembrar que [chamar `System.gc()` **não** garante que o GC será executado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105092/112052). A única coisa que sabemos é que determinados objetos estão elegíveis para serem coletados, mas quando isso será feito é algo que não controlamos.

Comment: O que você usou para fazer os desenhos?

Comment: @NatanFernandes https://balsamiq.com/wireframes/

Comment: obrigado a todos que ajudaram em especial ao @hkotsubo pela atenção, Deus te abençoe

Answer (score 2):

Em `7: Rabbit four = one` está atribuindo o valor da variável `one` para a variável `four`. E qual é o valor da variável `one` nesse momento? Basta olhar a linha anterior que acabou de atribuir um valor para `one` e a linha é `6: one = null;`, portanto em `four` o valor a ser atribuído é um `null`.

O que `null` tem a ver com qualquer `new Rabbit()` criado no código? Nada. Por alguma razão deve estar achando que tem. Ou está ignorando a linha 6 que anula o valor de `one`. `four` não aponta para objeto algum, não aponta para o objeto criado e guardado em `one` logo no começo.

Esse primeiro objeto chegou ter duas referências para ele, mas nunca chegou ter três. Então no momento que as duas referências deixam de existir o objeto está livre para ser coletado.

Pra mim esses desenhos são confusos, e no mínimo ele dá a entender algo que não acontece, talvez esteja errado mesmo, pelo menos é minha interpretação, que só não afirmo por causa da confusão. Ele não mostra o apontamento com clareza, e parece que `four` está apontando para `Rabbit` o que nunca acontece, em momento algum tem a linha 7 que faz `four` apontar para `null`.

Comment: entao nesse momento:

5: Rabbit three = one;
6: one = null;

após a linha 6 ele ja estaria elegível uma vez que todos que referenciarem one estarão apontando para null  seria isso?

Comment: Não, nem todos estão apontando para `null` na linha 6, apenas `one` está, o código diz exatamente isso, nada mais que isso.

Comment: mas o fato do 5: Rabbit three = one; consequentemente *three* nao vai está apontando para null?

Comment: Leia a linha, ela não diz que está apontando para `null`. Não enxergue coisas que não estão ocorrendo. è só o que o código diz.